# CSS -- Height 100% causes scrollbar

Tags: html, css

So I have some basic CSS (I'm using a framework so some of this overrides the default):

```
<style>html,body { height:100%; margin:0; } a {font-weight: bold;} body {background-color:#e0e0e0;} img {max-width:100%; height:auto;} .container { clear: both;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto;} .flow-text {font-size: 115%;} </style>
```

And here is my index.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Steelsite</title>
        <?php include ("includes/style.html");
include ("php/parsedown.php");?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include ("includes/navbar.html");
include ("includes/materialjs.html");?>
        <main>
            <div class="container white">
                <h3 class="center-align">Welcome to the site of James Heald</h3>


                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <div class="flow-text" style="font-size: 125%;">
                            <?php
$md = file_get_contents('md/index.md');
echo Parsedown::instance()->text($md); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col s12 m6">
                        <div class="center-align">
                            <img style="padding-top:1%; padding-bottom:1%;" class="responsive-img materialboxed" src="pictures/pi2.jpg" alt="The new home of steelcowboy.me!"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="divider"></div>

                <h5>From running "fortune":</h5><p class="flow-text" style="font-size: 115%;"><?php $fortune = system('fortune', $val); echo rtrim($val, "0");?>
                </p>
                <div class="container center-align">
                    <img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tags.png" class="responsive-img">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="scripts/google.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can view this live at https://steelcowboy.me

As you see, on the index page the white does not extend to the bottom of the page. However, if there is enough content (see https://steelcowboy.me/about.php) then it will indeed go to the bottom. The fix for the index page is `height:100%`; however, then on the "About Me" page I get an unwanted scrollbar. I think I have two things interacting that shouldn't necessarily be doing so, any suggestions on the best way to tackle this? Thanks!

Comment: you want that the point where the both arch Linux and photography block ends the page should end.There should be not extra scrollbar,

Comment: You can give `min-height` `.container` like: `min-height:300px;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSS for the main tag: `main {width:70%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; height:100%; background-color:#FFFFFF;}`

Edit the container class as follows: `width:100%;`

This will effectively create a second container around the DIV with the "container" class. Because it is the same background color, it will accomplish what you need. The container width had to be changed; otherwise, it would be 70% of its parent (which is main), making it much thinner than you originally intended. Let me know if it disrupts the about page.

*Note: for IE, you should also add `display:block` to the CSS code above.

Comment: That works absolutely great, thanks! However, in order to make the `main` block behave like the container, I had to add `@media screen and (max-width: 992px)` and tell it to make the main width at 85%; now it works *exactly* like the container. But my question is, why did we have to turn the main into the container? Why not just fix the container itself?

Comment: Because to fix the container it would have required us to give it some crazy height such as 2000-3000px. That would ensure that all pages, especially those with lengthy content, get "covered" by it. BTW the height of 100% only covers the visible screen area. Also, I chose 70% in my example because that's the width I saw when I inspected the container on your site. Best of luck.

Comment: Ah, mk. It made things a *little* more complicated, but it seems to work exactly like it should. Just had to make the width responsive like I mentioned, but otherwise it's perfect. Thank you very much for your help!